# How do I push a Jekyll site to GitHub which is already built?

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I have a site which I have built locally however due to it having entries in _plugins GitHub fails to build it upon commit. I understand you can build your site offline and then commit the built version - is this possible? If so, how do I achieve this whilst also checking in the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe everything is described here: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/ Have you seen this? If yes and something doesn't work for you let me know and I will try to help you further!

Comment: This won't allow me to store both generated and source content in the same repository from the looks of it

Comment: As far as I understand the docs you run `rake generate` first = you push generated site.

Comment: @Graeme: the source is stored in a branch (other than master), and the deployed site is stored in the master branch.

Comment: Also, add a `.nojekyll` file to your root to avoid Github from rebuilding & overriding your site when you push new code.